# Images not showing after path specified in header.php

Tags: theme-development

I am developing a WordPress site based on a theme developed using Twitter Bootstrap. I have a banner image specified in my `header.php` which is loaded at the top of every page.

**Added the image path**

After having made the requisite changes in the `header.php` to include the path

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory();?>/images/headerbg.jpg" alt="the image is not showing" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
```

*My image still does not show and the alt tag is shown*

[image]:

**Confirming the image path is correct and working**

*When directly using the computed code from the browser, I am able to access the image:*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) instead of [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/).

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/images/headerbg.jpg" ..../>
```

[`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) returns URI of the stylesheet directory where as [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/) returns the *path* on the server to the stylesheet directory.